# Application.properties in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, next.js

What is the purpose of the below property in springboot application.properties file ? *application_name*.app.next.config.web.webapp-name= *application_name*

Trying to create a webapp using next.js and springboot

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it's used to specify the name of the web application generated by Next.js

Answer (score 0):

The given property application_name.app.next.config.web.webapp-name= application_name in the application.properties file is used to set the name of the web application.

In this property, application_name is the name of the application which is being used as a prefix for all the properties in the file. The rest of the property path .app.next.config.web.webapp-name is used to specify the location where the value of this property should be stored.

In this case, the value of this property application_name is being set as the name of the web application.